# How to run PredictionIo Engine with MYSQL as a data source?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, predictionio

I have installed **PredictionIo**  engine from the following [link](https://predictionio.apache.org/install/install-sourcecode/) using the **first method**. Now I want to run the engine using **MYSQL** as a **datasource.**

So I have configured **env.sh** file as described below :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Copy this file as pio-env.sh and edit it for your site's configuration.
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# PredictionIO Main Configuration
#
# This section controls core behavior of PredictionIO. It is very likely that
# you need to change these to fit your site.

# SPARK_HOME: Apache Spark is a hard dependency and must be configured.
# SPARK_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7
SPARK_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6

POSTGRES_JDBC_DRIVER=$PIO_HOME/lib/postgresql-42.0.0.jar
MYSQL_JDBC_DRIVER=$PIO_HOME/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar


# PredictionIO Storage Configuration
#
# This section controls programs that make use of PredictionIO's built-in
# storage facilities. Default values are shown below.
#
# For more information on storage configuration please refer to
# http://predictionio.apache.org/system/anotherdatastore/

# Storage Repositories

# Default is to use PostgreSQL
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_meta
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=MYSQL

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=MYSQL

PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=MYSQL

# Storage Data Sources

# PostgreSQL Default Settings
# Please change "pio" to your database name in PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_URL
# Please change PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_USERNAME and
# PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_PASSWORD accordingly
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_TYPE=jdbc
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/pio
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_USERNAME=pio
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_PGSQL_PASSWORD=pio

# MySQL Example
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_TYPE=jdbc
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pio
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_USERNAME=root
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
```

I have also placed the mysql-java-connector jar in pio_home/lib directory.
However when I run **pio status** command, I get the following error :

```
[INFO] [Management$] PredictionIO 0.12.1 is installed at /home/oodles/predictionio/PredictionIO-0.12.1
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting Apache Spark...
[INFO] [Management$] Apache Spark is installed at /home/oodles/predictionio/PredictionIO-0.12.1/vendors/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6
[INFO] [Management$] Apache Spark 2.1.1 detected (meets minimum requirement of 1.3.0)
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting storage backend connections...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Meta Data Backend (Source: MYSQL)...
[ERROR] [Management$] Unable to connect to all storage backends successfully.
The following shows the error message from the storage backend.

No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pio (java.sql.SQLException)

Dumping configuration of initialized storage backend sources.
Please make sure they are correct.

Source Name: MYSQL; Type: jdbc; Configuration: PASSWORD -> root, URL -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pio, TYPE -> jdbc, USERNAME -> root
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pio` to `jdbc:mysql://localhost/pio` in env.sh file

Comment: It did not worked either :

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/pio

Comment: Can you check $PIO_HOME is set or not. Or you can give the all whole path of driver.

Comment: May be mysql driver local is different. Because above changes work for me.

Comment: $PIO_HOME is set for session only.

Comment: I am using predictionIO from last 1 year using mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar driver

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue and this is because the JDBC driver is not installed although you would think it is from the pio-env.sh saying there is a jar file of some sort. What you want to do is go to this site https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and then choose the "Platform Independent" option and then click the download button. This Oracle website is trying to make you sign up for something but don't do it. Go to the bottom of the page where it says "No thanks, just start my download" and right click and save that link. You can now "wget" command to get the file and then unzip that file in your linux/ubuntu environment. I forget what the unzip command file is. I am noob to linux/unix environments but this did work for me with PIO.